# why we refer the dimens.xml file in android with @dimen not @dimens?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have made a new value resource file in the android studio project as name **dimens**
but while referring to it from XML I have to use the attribute @dimen

I am really curious to know the referring tag must have to be the same as the file name but it is not.

I have seen the same pattern in strings and colors.

But it is like that? any clue?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

name of your files doesn't matter in fact, you can rename `dimens.xml` to `anything.xml`. Or you can have `dimen_activity.xml` and `dimen_fragment.xml` files, which helps you manage them.  Also, you can keep in this file `<dimen` tags, but also `<integer`s and any other (e.g. you can have one `sizes.xml` file). Resources are built upon content inside all XML files placed in `values`, a kind-of map is created then and all `<dimen`s from all XML files are available under `@dimen/` or `R.dimen.`